# Some of my LEDs managed to light up but the others just won't work no matter what I do, what could be the reason for this?

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, proteus, pcb-simulation

This is a picture of my schematic and I want to ask what could be the reason why the ones below won't light up

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wdr1.png):[image] https://i.stack.imgur.com/REuys.png

Comment: remove D1 to D8 from the circuit ... compare the connections to the two remaining LEDs

Comment: The bottom LEDs have their anode going to a banana plug or something. It needs external connection via banana plug. Do you have that banana plug connection? Or do you expect the LEDs to light up without one?

Answer (score 4):

The GPIO pins for the lower LEDs are connected to GND.